# how to split array into n groups? (factorize, or _.partition array)

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

Let's say I have an array = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6] and I want to "partition" it into 3 arrays, based on reminder after division by 3.

so basically I'd want something like:

```
_.my_partition([0,1,2,3,4,5,6], function(item) {return item % 3;})
// [[0,3,6], [1,4],[2,5]]
```

(I can use lodash, underscore, if ti helps...)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are multiple to do this:

**I. Normal function**

```
function partition(items, n) {
    var result = _.groupBy(items, function(item, i) {
        return Math.floor(i % n);
    });
    return _.values(result);
}

myArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
partition(myArray, 3);
```

**II. Adding a prototype method**

```
Array.prototype.partition = function(n) {
    var result = _.groupBy(this, function(item, i) {
        return Math.floor(i % n);
    });
    return _.values(result);
}

myArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
myArray.partition(3)
```

**Create an _.partitionToGroups method**

```
_.partitionToGroups = function(items, n) {
    var result = _.groupBy(items, function(item, i) {
        return Math.floor(i % n);
    });
    return _.values(result);
}

myArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
_.partitionToGroups(myArray, 3);
```

Comment: Be careful with the third approach, lodash already has a [partition()](https://lodash.com/docs#partition) function.

Comment: Thanks for this @AdamBoduch . Let's rename it to partitionToGroups

Comment: In lodash 4, the index argument was removed from the `groupBy` callback, so you need to keep track of it on your own.

Comment: first "normal function" does nothing to split them. I copy-paste the code to the console and it outputs an Array of 10 items inside another array :/