# How to partition array into multiple groups using Lodash?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm trying to find a concise way to partition an array of objects into groups of arrays based on a predicate.

```
var arr = [
  {id: 1, val: 'a'}, 
  {id: 1, val: 'b'}, 
  {id: 2, val: 'c'}, 
  {id: 3, val: 'a'}
];

//transform to below

var partitionedById = [
  [{id: 1, val: 'a'}, {id: 1, val:'b'}], 
  [{id: 2, val: 'c'}], 
  [{id: 3, val: 'a'}
];
```

I see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29538967/how-to-split-array-into-n-groups-factorize-or-partition-array) , which gives a good overview using plain JS, but I'm wondering if there's a more concise way to do this using lodash?  I see the [partition function](https://lodash.com/docs#partition) but it only splits the arrays into 2 groups (need it to be 'n' number of partitions).  The [groupBy](https://lodash.com/docs#groupBy) groups it into an object by keys, I'm looking for the same but in an array (without keys).

Is there a simpler way to maybe nest a couple lodash functions to achieve this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can first group by `id`, which will yield an object where the keys are the different values of `id` and the values are an array of all array items with that id, which is basically what you want (use [`_.values()`](https://lodash.com/docs#values) to get just the value arrays):

```
// "regular" version
var partitionedById = _.values(_.groupBy(arr, 'id'));

// chained version
var partitionedById = _(arr).groupBy('id').values().value();
```

Comment: Thanks!  wasn't aware of the _.values() function